# how to run for 30 minutes with 10 users read from csv file

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, load-testing

I'm new to jmeter. I have a thread group with login request.
I have a csv file of 10 users with login credentials.
I have to run for 30 minutes with 10 users reading from csv file using csv dataset config.
how can set options in csv dataset config for this scenario?

Comment: do you want to keep login over and over with same 10 users until 30 minutes are over?

Comment: yes,i tried,i set in thread group users=10 ,duration=30 minutes. but test completes in few seconds... not run for 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can execute it using Duration value, but set it with **seconds**.

For 30 minutes you need to set value to 1800

Also set Loop Count (with checkbox) value to `Forever` so execution will be controlled only using Duration, see [tutorial](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/jmeter-tutorials/scheduler-configuration-example-in-jmeter).

Notice that You shouldn't have any stop operation, also meaning:

In `CSV Data Set Config` parameter `Recycle on EOF` should be `TRUE` and `Stop Thread on EOF` should be `FALSE`.

Comment: I set the same settings in thread group... and set as recycle on EOF is false ,stop thread on EOF =true in csv dataset config... Is i'm right?

Comment: You shouldn't have stop operation, for example i n `CSV Data Set Config` `Recycle on EOF` should be `TRUE` and `Stop Thread on EOF` should be `FALSE`

Comment: But I need to execute only 10 concurrent users load while login. If I give recycle on EOF is true, and stop thread on EOF is false, the 10 uses will perform multiple time logins. For example thread group having  7 requests.Then 10 users will perform 10*7=70 total samples and each request will execute more  than 10 times

Comment: The users will keep on running till the duration ends with multiple times right

Comment: You can add after login, all your requests under `Runtime Controller` with 600 seconds

Comment: What is the use of runtime controller with specify 600 seconds?

Comment: You are right. In your case you will need 1800 seconds (minus login time maybe)